# Convert JSON object to a specific format

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to get the `locations` in this format from Json response:

```
 var locations = [
        ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
        ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
        ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
        ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
        ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
      ];
```

This is my Json response:

```
[{"Name":"Bondi Beach","Longitute":-33.890542,"Latitute":151.274856,"Position":1},{"Name":"Coogee Beach","Longitute":-33.923036,"Latitute":151.259052,"Position":2}]
```

At the moment I'm doing the following but I have problems converting

```
 var locations;
      var myArray;
      $.getJSON(
       "/top3/DesktopModules/LBSecurity/API/ModuleTask/GetProduct?ProductID=1",
      function (result) {
          var parsed = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
         //Problem is here
         myArray = parsed.map(function (e) {
              return [e.Name, e.Longitute, e.Latitute, e.Position];
          });
         myArray = parsed;  
      });
 locations = myArray;
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Edit #1 - Complete code

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="themap" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
      var locations;
      var myArray;
      $.getJSON(
       "/top3/DesktopModules/LBSecurity/API/ModuleTask/GetProduct?UserID=1",
      function (result) {
          var parsed = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
          myArray = parsed.map(function (e) {
              return [e.Name, e.Longitute, e.Latitute, e.Position];
          });

          //Place this inside the callback function
          locations = myArray;        
      });

      //var locations = [
      //  ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
      //  ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
      //  ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
      //  ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
      //  ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
      //];

      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('themap'), {
          zoom: 10,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      });

      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

      var marker, i;

      for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
          marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
              map: map
          });

          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
              return function () {
                  infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                  infowindow.open(map, marker);
              }
          })(marker, i));
      }
  </script>
```

Comment: Are you sure that's where the problem is? Calling `parseJSON()` on what should already *be* an object seems weird. Apart from that, you're setting `locations = myArray` just after the `getJSON()` call; the JSON request has almost certainly *not* completed yet, so `myArray` will still be undefined.

Comment: `myArray = parsed;` is cancelling your `.map()`

Comment: @PaulRoub Paul, I am totally beginner in Javascript. I'm just hanging from various examples...

Comment: you can use `JSON.parse` with reviever function, something like `JSON.parse(t, function(k,v){

if(k && isFinite(Number(k))) return [v.Name, v.Longitute, v.Latitute, v.Position]

return v;
})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.map()` function is fine ([**See an example**](http://jsfiddle.net/LcSalazar/w5p6q0h4/)), so I'll point out two things that seem out of place. It should work well.

Removed one statement, and placed the last assignment inside the callback function:

```
var locations;
var myArray;
$.getJSON("/top3/DesktopModules/LBSecurity/API/ModuleTask/GetProduct?ProductID=1",
    function (result) {
        var parsed = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
        myArray = parsed.map(function (e) {
            return [e.Name, e.Longitute, e.Latitute, e.Position];
        });

        //Place this inside the callback function
        locations = myArray;

        /* REMOVE THE LINE: myArray = parsed; */
    }
);
```

**EDIT**

You must remember that everything else must be executed after the `.getJSON()` is finished. Here's an idea using a separate function:

```
var locations;
var myArray;
$.getJSON("/top3/DesktopModules/LBSecurity/API/ModuleTask/GetProduct?ProductID=1",
    function (result) {
        var parsed = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
        myArray = parsed.map(function (e) {
            return [e.Name, e.Longitute, e.Latitute, e.Position];
        });
        locations = myArray;
        MapFunction();
    }
);

function MapFunction() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('themap'), {
      zoom: 10,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  var marker, i;

  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
          map: map
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
          return function () {
              infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
              infowindow.open(map, marker);
          }
      })(marker, i));
  }
}
```

Comment: I have edited the question and added the complete code using your edits. However it still doesn't work..

Answer (score 0):

```
var locations;
var myArray;
$.getJSON("/top3/DesktopModules/LBSecurity/API/ModuleTask/GetProduct?ProductID=1",
function (result) {
var result= [{"Name":"BondiBeach","Longitute":-33.890542,"Latitute":151.274856,"Position":1},{"Name":"Coogee Beach","Longitute":-33.923036,"Latitute":151.259052,"Position":2}]
var parsed = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
 myArray = parsed.map(function (e) {
 return [e.Name, e.Longitute, e.Latitute, e.Position];
 });
  locations = myArray;
}
);
```

- try this one store your JSON inside result variable. then pass result inside Parse JSON method

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JSON.parse with reviver function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

like

```
locations = JSON.parse(result, function(k,v){
    if(k && isFinite(Number(k))) return [v.Name, v.Longitute, v.Latitute, v.Position];
    return v; 
});
```

and for `'[{"Name":"Bondi Beach","Longitute":-33.890542,"Latitute":151.274856,"Position":1},{"Name":"Coogee Beach","Longitute":-33.923036,"Latitute":151.259052,"Position":2}]'` you get

```
[
  [
    "Bondi Beach",
    -33.890542,
    151.274856,
    1
  ],
  [
    "Coogee Beach",
    -33.923036,
    151.259052,
    2
  ]
]
```